# How to get a column inside another column?

Tags: sql, arrays, string, select, google-bigquery

I’m trying to run the column

> name.pt_BR

that’s inside the column

> name

but I didn’t understand how to get this in BigQuery.

How to get this info to join in another query later?

```
SELECT name.pt_BR FROM `source_internal.skills`
```

Returns the error

```
Cannot access field pt_BR on a value with type ARRAY<STRUCT<pt_BR STRING, en STRING>> at [1:13]
```

The column:

**name**

name.**pt_BR**

name.**en**
￼

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below.

```
SELECT pt_BR 
FROM `source_internal.skills`, UNNEST(name)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!